# product of positive and negative semidefinite matrices

Tags: matrices

Suppose we have two matrices $A$ and $B$ in which $A \preceq 0$ and $B \succeq 0$. If $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = 0$, can we conclude $AB = 0$ ? Say, $A$ and $B$ are all symmetric.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is really no need to say A B are all symmetric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  WLOG we can assume $A$ is diagonal.  Then $\text{tr}(AB) = \sum_j a_{jj} b_{jj}$.  Since $a_{jj} \le 0$ and $b_{jj} \ge 0$, the only way this can be $0$ is all $a_{jj} b_{jj} = 0$.
But if $B$ is positive semidefinite and $b_{jj} = 0$, we must have $b_{jk} = 0$ for all $k$, 
so $(AB)_{jk} = a_{jj} b_{jk} = 0$.

Comment: Got you. Thanks a lot!