# Product of semidefinite matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$,$B$ are square $n\times n$ matrixes with real entries. $A$ is positive semidefinite and $B$ is negative semidefinite. Then we know that $AB$ is negative semidefinite. Suppose that $trace(AB)=0$.

> Can we get some more information on the matrixes $A$ and $B$?

thank you

Comment: The following is related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110184/product-of-positive-and-negative-semidefinite-matrices?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is not true that $AB$ is negative semidefinite. Let 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\3&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $A$ is positive semidefinite, $B$ is negative semidefinite, but $AB$ is neither:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}^TAB\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=18,\ \ \
\begin{bmatrix}11\\-12\end{bmatrix}^TAB\begin{bmatrix}11\\-12\end{bmatrix}=-7.
$$

Regarding your concrete question, I don't think you can say anything about your matrices: let $A_0$ be any positive semidefinite matrix, $B_0$ any negative semidefinite matrix, and let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}A_0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0& B_0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $AB=0$, so $\mbox{tr}(AB)=0$.